# How to get number of context switches for a pid in osx

Tags: macos, operating-system, profiling, cpu, context-switch

Hey guys essentially looking for a /proc/pid/status equivalent in osx.

Was looking at man ps. And tried 'ps -A -o nswap,nivcsw' ... didn't seem to show anything though.